# xargs - append each argument with a parameter

Tags: bash, shell-script, xargs

I know that, given `l="a b c"`,

```
echo $l | xargs ls
```

yields

```
ls a b c
```

Which construct yields

```
mycommand -f a -f b -f c
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
echo "a b c" | xargs printf -- '-f %s\n' | xargs mycommand
```

This assumes `a`, `b`, and `c` don't contain blanks, newlines, quotes or backslashes. :)

With GNU `findutil` you can handle the general case, but it's slightly more complicated:

```
echo -n "a|b|c" | tr \| \\0 | xargs -0 printf -- '-f\0%s\0' | xargs -0 mycommand
```

You can replace the `|` separator with some other character, that doesn't appear in `a`, `b`, or `c`.

**Edit:** As [@MichaelMol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138669/michael-mol) notes, with a very long list of arguments there is a risk of overflowing the maximum length of arguments that can be passed to `mycommand`.  When that happens, the last `xargs` will split the list and run another copy of `mycommand`, and there is a risk of it leaving an unterminated `-f`.  If you worry about that situation you could replace the last `xargs -0` above by something like this:

```
... | xargs -x -0 mycommand
```

This won't solve the problem, but it would abort running `mycommand` when the list of arguments gets too long.

Comment: You run a pretty ugly risk of exceeding `ARG_MAX` and having a `-f` separated from its paired parameter.

Comment: @MichaelMol That's a good point, but I don't think there is any meaningful way to handle that situation without knowing more about `mycommand`.  You could always add `-x` to the last `xargs`.

Comment: I think the proper solution is probably not to use `xargs` at all, and just use `find` if it can be used. This solution is dangerous; you should at least warn of the failure case in your answer.

Comment: @MichaelMol I really don't see how `find` would be a better general solution, particularly when the initial arguments aren't filenames. :)

Comment: We don't know what the initial arguments are; we only see the example given, not the scenario that inspired the question. Intuition suggests that with an argument named `-f`, and with an example tool `ls` used for illustration, @not-a-user is dealing with filenames. And given `find` offers the `-exec` argument, which allows you to *construct* a command-line, it's fine. (So long as `mycommand` is permitted to execute more than once. If it's not, then we have another problem with the use of `xargs` here...)

Comment: @MichaelMol As I said: `xargs -x`.

Comment: And now we're not processing all input lines. Are you going to reflect these caveats in your answer? **edit:** Ah, I see you did, now.

Comment: Instead of `echo $l | xargs printf ...` (which is closer to the actual question) one could write more simply `printf ... $l`.

Comment: Instead of `-x` you can set `-n` to a reasonable even value like 1024 if multiple executions of `mycommand` make sense

Answer (score 6):

A better way to address it (IMO) would be:

- in `zsh`:

  ```
  l=(a b c)
  mycommand -f$^l
  ```

  or using array zipping so the argument be not attached to the option:

  ```
  l=(a b c) o=(-f)
  mycommand "${o:^^l}"
  ```

  That way, it still works if the `l` array contains empty elements or elements containing spaces or any other problematic character for `xargs`. Example:

  ```
  $ l=(a '' '"' 'x y' c) o=(-f)
  $ printf '<%s>\n' "${o:^^l}"
  <-f>
  <a>
  <-f>
  <>
  <-f>
  <">
  <-f>
  <x y>
  <-f>
  <c>
  ```
- in `rc`:

  ```
  l=(a b c)
  mycommand -f$l
  ```
- in `fish`:

  ```
  set l a b c
  mycommand -f$l
  ```

(AFAIK, `rc` and `fish` have no array zipping)

With old-style Bourne-like shells like `bash`, you could always do (still allowing any character in the elements of the `$@` array):

```
set -- a b c
for i do set -- "$@" -f "$i"; shift; done
mycommand "$@"
```

Comment: Another way to do it in bash is with a named array variable.  `for i; do args+=('-f' "$i");done;` `mycommand "${args[@]}"`.  IDK if this is faster, but appending 2 elements to an array seems like it should be O(n), while your `set` loop probably copies and re-parses the accumulated arg list every time (O(n^2)).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to prefix arguments is via `printf` in conjunction with [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```bsh
l="a b c"

mycommand $(printf ' -f %s' $l)
```

Alternatively, the command substitution `$()` can be rewritten by piping to `xargs`:

```bsh
printf ' -f %s' $l | xargs mycommand
```

The command substitution allows to control location of the dynamic arguments in the argument list. For instance, you can prepend, append, or even place the arguments anywhere in between any other fixed arguments to be passed to `mycommand`.

The `xargs` approach works best to append arguments to the end, but it requires a more obscure syntax to handle different placement of dynamic arguments among fixed ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my real-world example. It's a quick'n'dirty hack but it works.

```
docker-compose exec postfix mailq | egrep '^[A-Z0-9]{8}' | cut -f 1 -d " " | \
  xargs printf -- '-d %s\n' | \
  xargs -n4 -d '\n' echo "docker-compose exec -- postfix postsuper"
```

The above will generate this kind of output:

```
docker-compose exec -- postfix postsuper -d 794B95AB886 -d 7D2375AA207
docker-compose exec -- postfix postsuper -d 0A6AE5AA244 -d 048D85AA231
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend `-f`:

```
echo 'a b c' | xargs -n 1 echo -e -f | xargs mycommand
```

> The -e argument is there to avoid -f being interpreted as another argument

If you instead want an output like this one (a, b, and c are each between an -f and a -g):

```
mycommand -f a -g -f b -g -f c -g
```

Then the command would be this one:

```
echo 'a b c' | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I @ echo -e -f @ -g | xargs mycommand
```

Comment: Many `echo` implementations output `-e<newline>` upon `echo -e`. I don't know of any that accepts `-f` as an option though. See also [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)